# Debug node modules in nwjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

We're developing an application based on node webkit (nwjs) that is a mix of node modules and angular code. A lot of business logic has been moved to the node modules and I haven't found a way to debug that code in the running application.

Debugging with devtools doesn't seem to work, and that's a known limitation or bug ([Debugging with devtools](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Debugging-with-devtools)). I even tried to require `node-monkey` from one of the scripts, hoping to be able to open some sort of backdoor ;) - didn't work unfortunately.

So is there any other way or trick to (remote) debug the code?

Comment: I might suggest trying Node.js Tools for Visual Studio ( https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/ ) - Disclaimer: I'm involved with this project.

Comment: @Dai, would you care to post an answer detailing how to use your tool in this particular case? As it is, your link is not too useful.

Comment: @Dai Hmm, does it solve the special remote-debugging problem with nw.js? Debugging plain node is not a challenge, I'm happy with intellij

Comment: Have you made any progress? This is a serious problem for me at the moment. I'd love to hear if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Chrome Debugger Extension to debug my node modules in my nwjs app.

Here's the config in launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Launch nwjs",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src", //where you put your .js files
    "runtimeExecutable": "nw"
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "--chrome-remote-port=9222"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "diagnosticLogging": true,
    "port": 9222
},
```

I had to change some files from VS Code since the editor ignores URL's that starts with chrome-extension:// by default and the Nwjs runs your app under this protocol...

This Issue on GitHub helped me alot.

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4919

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector)

You should be able to start your application with `node-debug` instead of `node` and it will open chrome devtools looking inside your app.

You can also use this to debug a remote server.

You can then add breakpoints, watch variables, etc as you would if you were debugging a web application.

Comment: The question is asking about NodeWebkit